# Are there any other honorific particles apart from 께서 and 께?

Tags: honorific, particle

께서 is an honorific version of 이/가 :

> 아버님께서는 무엇을 하세요?
>
> What does your father do?

께 is an honorific version of 에게/한테:

> 할머님께 편지를 썼습니다.
>
> I wrote Grandmother a letter.

<sub>examples from http://www.korean.arts.ubc.ca/b_tb/tb_13/L13-2-2.htm</sub>

Are there any other honorific particles, e.g. for 을/를, 에서, and so on? or are 께서 and 께 the only ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no other honorific particles other than '께서' and '께' that could be used in your examples. Out of the two particles, '께서' is not always required when making an honorific. For example,

> 아버님은 무엇을 하세요? What does your father do (for a living)?

doesn't sound non-honorific as '아버님' is honorific for '아버지 or 아빠' and '하시다' is honorific for '하다' . "아버님께서는 무엇을 하세요" sounds more honorific and formal than the above sentence.

However, '께' is more broadly used than '께서' when making an honorific sentence.